# How to make a sheet scroll to the last row with data once a button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked through the forum, as well as Google, and I wasn't able to find an answer to what I'm trying to do.

One of the users [here][1] helped me get a code to copy data in a specific row (upon clicking a button) to the last row of a table that is found further down in the same sheet.

However, I'd like the sheet to scroll down to the last non-empty row of the table instead of scrolling manually. I understand that this can be accomplished through a combination of CTRL+SHIFT+"DOWN ARROW". However; the excel users are not very good with computers, so I am trying to make it as simple as possible to them.

Is there a VBA code that can do the job?

Thanks

So far, I am using Erin's code, which takes me to the last row of the spread sheet, instead of the last Non-Blank row. This could be because column A has formulas in all its cells, all the way down to the last cell. However, column A cells formulas are set to give blank unless there's data entered in their adjacent cells in column E.

Here's the code that I am using, which is pasted in the module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

' define which worksheet to work on, i.e. replace Sheet1 with the name of 
your sheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1. Clients Details")

' determine the last row with content in column E and add one
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' copy some cells into their ranges
ws.Range("E3:G3").Copy ws.Range("E" & lRow)
ws.[E1].Select

' combine H3, I3, J3, K3 and L3 and copy into column E, next empty row 
ws.Range("H" & lRow) = ws.[H3] & " " & ws.[I3] & " " & ws.[J3] & ", " & ws.
[K3] & " " & ws.[L3]

' copy the other cells into their ranges
ws.Range("M3:Q3").Copy ws.Range("M" & lRow)
ws.[M1].Select

' combine H3 & I3
ws.Range("AA" & lRow) = ws.[H3] & " " & ws.[I3]

' combine J3, K3 & L3
ws.Range("AB" & lRow) = ws.[J3] & "       " & ws.[K3] & "       " & ws.[L3]


' copy Q3 into column Q only, if F3 = "Company"
If Worksheets("1. Clients Details").Range("F3").Value = "Company" Then
ws.Range("Q3").Copy ws.Range("Q" & lRow)

End If
Call scrollToEnd
End Sub

Sub scrollToEnd()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim numRows As Long
numRows = Range("E1:E1000").Rows.count
lastrow = Range("E1:E1000").Columns(5).Rows(numRows).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("E" & lastrow).Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lastrow as long
Dim numRows as long
numRows = Range ("TableName").Rows.Count
lastRow = Range ("TableName").Columns (1).Rows(numRows).Row

Activesheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Activate
```

I can't test it right now,  but I believe this will work.  If you know the offset for your table, you can just do numRows + offset (mine are usually in A1, so I just add 1 for the header - numRows is data rows) to get your row number for the .Activate. :-)

Or to reach the same row as CTRL+SHIFT+"DOWN ARROW", regardless of the table:

```
With Activesheet
   .Range("A" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row).Activate
End With
```

EDITED: I was thinking CTRL+END in the above code.  To simulate CTRL+"DOWN ARROW" (adding SHIFT selects everything in its path...), you would actually use:

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Activate
```

You could simply paste this at the end of your sub since it is one line, or keep it as its own little sub if you are wanting to call it from a button-click.  If it is column E that you want selected, you would simply replace "A1" with "E1".

This does assume that there are no blank cells in column E between "E1" and the last non-blank row.  Otherwise, you will need to use the same logic as in your copyRow sub to find the last non-blank row:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Activate
```

Comment: Hi Erin,

Sorry, I'm still considered a beginner to excel VBA.
Could you please tell me where to paste this code, bearing in mind that I have another code pasted in the Module, which is can be seen in the link provided earlier

Comment: Are you wanting this scroll to happen immediately after pasting the row, or is the user clicking a button and being taken to the last row?

Comment: I wanted this to happen upon clicking of a button. But if you can give me both options, for learning purposes, that will be great!

Comment: At the bottom of your module, create a sub scolllToEnd and put the code in this.  To happen on button click, right-click the button, choose "Assign Macro", and then select scrollToEnd from the list.  To happen immediately after pasting, add the line "Call scrollToEnd" at the end of sub copyRow.

Comment: Hi Erin,

Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the button scrolls the spreadsheet all the way to the last column and not the last non-blank cell.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you paste in the code you are using?  I made a little update to the first option (I should have used .Rows(numRows)) to make it actually move beyond row 2 and changed the second option to allow for unused cells above the table, but even before the changes, both took me to a cell in column A.

Comment: Hi Erin.

Thank you for that. I have used your code, but it takes me to the last cell of the spreadsheet. I edited my original addressing the problem and my suggestion if what could trigger it. Could you please help me get this right?

Comment: Ah...you have blank used cells underneath your data (and perhaps not turned into an Excel table...?).  That makes a difference!  Also, I was thinking the wrong key combination.  I have updated my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This will scroll down till the last row's cell is at the top left of the screen.

```
Sub test()

Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp), True  'where 'A' is the column of the last row

End Sub
```

You can paste the code at the bottom of your current procedure or assign it to a button.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you can try this. This will find the last row of any column.

```
Sub test()

Dim lastrow As Range
Set lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not lastrow Is Nothing Then Application.Goto lastrow, True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi idktho. Your code did not do anything. I pasted it in the same module sheet as my other code for copying rows, right at the bottom of it. 
This got me thinking how do I refer the sheet that I am using to this VBA code, as your code has no reference to a sheet name. Excuse me I sound dumb lol

Comment: @Omar Oops, I totally forgot about that. Please try the amended code.

Comment: Thanks idktho. It's still not doing anything :(

Comment: @Omar What do you mean by not doing anything? Where did you put the code?

Comment: I had to change the the final line of the second option to `If Not lastrow Is Nothing Then Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow.Row, 1), True` to get to the first column, but both of these options worked for me.

Comment: Hi Erin,

THANK YOU SO MUCH. I have used the code you gave me:
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Activate
and it did the job great. 
{We are to our creator Allah and to Him we shall return}